# SQLAlchemy create_all() does not create tables in to mysql when i import models class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to integrate Mysql and SQLAlchemy but SQLAlchemy.create_all() is not creating any tables from my models.
this is my code

```
//Patient class
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlalchemy
from os import getenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime
import uuid
from typing import TypeVar, List, Iterable
from os import path
from datetime import datetime
from models.base_person import BasePerson

Base = declarative_base()


class Patient(BasePerson, Base):

    __tablename__ = 'patients'
    appointement_payement = relationship("AppointementPayement", backref="Patient", cascade="delete")
```

// AppointementPayement file (appointement_payement.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlalchemy
from os import getenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Numeric,  ForeignKey
import uuid
from typing import TypeVar, List, Iterable
from os import path
from datetime import datetime
from models.base_person import BasePerson
#from models.engine.db_storage import MDBStorage

#from models.base import Base
Base = declarative_base()
from models.base import BaseModel

class AppointementPayement(BaseModel, Base):

    __tablename__ = 'appointement_payement'
    payement_amount = Column(Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    payement_method = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    patient_id = Column(String(60), ForeignKey('patients.id'), nullable=False)
```

// base

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlalchemy
from os import getenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Boolean
import uuid
from typing import TypeVar, List, Iterable
from os import path
from datetime import datetime
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

Base = declarative_base()


class BaseModel:
    id = Column(String(60), primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

// the class that is supposed to create the classes (db_storage.py)

```
from models.base_person import BasePerson
from models.base import Base
from os import getenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, scoped_session, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, create_engine, Numeric, ForeignKey, Text
import uuid
from typing import TypeVar, List, Iterable
from os import path
from datetime import datetime
from models.patient import Patient
from models.appointement_payement import AppointementPayement
Base = declarative_base()
class MDBStorage:
    """interaacts with the MySQL database"""
    __engine = None
    __session = None

    def __init__(self):
        """Instantiate a DBStorage object"""
         PRIMETEL_MYSQL_USER = getenv('PRIMETEL_MYSQL_USER')
         PRIMETEL_MYSQL_PWD = getenv('PRIMETEL_MYSQL_PWD')
         PRIMETEL_MYSQL_HOST = getenv('PRIMETEL_MYSQL_HOST')
         PRIMETEL_MYSQL_DB = getenv('PRIMETEL_MYSQL_DB')
         self.__engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@{}/{}'.
                                            format('PRIMETEL_MYSQL_USER',
                                                   'PRIMETEL_MYSQL_PWD',
                                                   'PRIMETEL_MYSQL_HOST',
                                                   'PRIMETEL_MYSQL_DB'), echo=True)

    def reload(self):
        """reloads data from the database"""
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.__engine)
        sess_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.__engine, expire_on_commit=False)
        Session = scoped_session(sess_factory)
        self.__session = Session

    def close(self):
        """call remove() method on the private session attribute"""
        self.__session.remove()
```

// **init**.py, instantiation of the class MDBStorage

```
from models.engine.db_storage import MDBStorage


storage = MDBStorage()
storage.reload()
```

But when i put all models class in db_storage.py and also creat an object of MDBStorage and invoqued reload(), all table are created. i use SQLAlchemy 2.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is related to how the `declarative_base` is being used in your code. You have defined `Base` multiple times in different files, which is causing SQLAlchemy to lose track of the table definitions.

To fix this issue create a single `base.py` file where you define `Base` and import it in all other model files:

**base.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

Then, in your model files, import Base from `base.py`

**patient.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime
from models.base_person import BasePerson
from models.base import Base

class Patient(BasePerson, Base):
    # rest of the code
```

**appointement_payement.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Numeric, ForeignKey
from models.base_person import BasePerson
from models.base import Base, BaseModel

class AppointementPayement(BaseModel, Base):
    # rest of the code
```

**db_storage.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, create_engine, Numeric, ForeignKey, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session, relationship
from models.patient import Patient
from models.appointement_payement import AppointementPayement
from models.base import Base

class MDBStorage:
    # rest of the code
```

You need to update the format string in the `__init__` method of `MDBStorage` class to properly use the environment variables.

```py
self.__engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@{}/{}'.
                              format(PRIMETEL_MYSQL_USER,
                                     PRIMETEL_MYSQL_PWD,
                                     PRIMETEL_MYSQL_HOST,
                                     PRIMETEL_MYSQL_DB), echo=True)
```

SQLAlchemy should be able to create the tables as expected.